# CascadeType.DETACH isn't being propagated through a @ManyToMany relationship in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, cascade

I'm trying to clone a post object. To do this, I'm setting it's ID to `null`, then detaching it using `entityManager` and then saving it.

Regarding the post comments, I let `CascadeType.DETACH` do the job to propagate the change. Consider the next piece of code to illustrate the issue:

```java
// PostService.java
private void clonePost(Post post) {
  post.setId(null);
  post.getComments().forEach(comment -> comment.setId(null));

  entityManager.detach(post); // CascadeType will take care of detaching the comments
  postRepository.save(post);  // now we have a duplicated post with the same comments

  // Since it's a detached entity and has no ID, Hibernate will treat it as a 
  // new entity and save it creating a new record
}
```

Now, there's a catch. Here's the `Post` class:

```java
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 50, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;
    
    // ...
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    
    // ...
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tags", 
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_tag_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private Set<PostTag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

The post `tags` use a `@ManyToMany` unidirectional relationship to which `Post` is the owner, and also are lazily fetch. Usually, detaching the post would cause the tags to detach too, because the `cascade = CascadeType.DETACH` set in `@ManyToMany`.

However, that is not happening. The tags aren't being detached. It does seem that laziness have some sort of effect that prevents the detach to propagate adequately, since doing it manually or initializing the tags fixes the issue:

```java
private void clonePost(Post post) {
    // ...
    
    // option 1 - manual detaching
    post.getTags().forEach(tag -> entityManager.detach(tag)); 
    
    // option 2 - initializing tags allows the detach of the post to propagate to them
    post.getTags().forEach(tag -> Hibernate.initialize(tag));

    entityManager.detach(post);
    postRepository.save(post);
}
```

Both options can be avoided if the tags are set to load eagerly:

```java
public class Post {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tags", 
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_tag_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    // @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) // this fetch mode will also make the tags to load eager
    private Set<PostTag> tags = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Why is this happening? Why doesn't `CascadeType.DETACH` propagate to a lazily loaded `@ManyToMany` collection when the parent is detached?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it happens by the same reason as for the `REMOVE`. Hibernate documentation [says](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-unidirectional):

> For `@ManyToMany` associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`.
>
> For example, if `@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` was defined and the first person would be deleted, Hibernate would throw an exception because another person is still associated with the address that’s being deleted.

```
Person person1 = entityManager.find(Person.class, personId);
entityManager.remove(person1);

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FKM7J0BNABH2YR0PE99IL1D066U table: PERSON_ADDRESS
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @SternK. It's to my understanding that `REMOVE` doesn't have the same behavior as `DETACH`. In fact, if the collection is set to load eagerly, `DETACH` propagation works as expected. It's when the collection loads lazily that it doesn't propagate.